# Unity Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to make an Audio Manager, but Unity cannot convert method group to non-delegate type.
here is the code for AudioManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Audio[] sounds;

    void Awake() {

        foreach (Audio s in sounds) {

            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>;
            s.source.clip = s.clip;

            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;

        }

    }

}
```

and here is my code for Audio:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

[System.Serializable]

public class Audio {

    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume;
    [Range(.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch;

    public AudioSource source;

}
```

Also I am new to unity so probably I did something wrong.

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Comment: Missing `()` after `s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>` .. I vote to close this as typo-based :) Note however: You are trying to add multiple `AudioSource` components to the same `gameObject` .. why? Couldn't you then just use a single `AudioSource`?

Comment: its definitely a good question ( @derHugo )  We actually do that, what I mean is in the editor.  Say there are 20 sfx in the game (so, bang, yell, bell etc etc). In the editor, I actually just boringly put 20 AudioSource on a gameobject somewhere. then I tediously set each one of those to one of the sound files (bang, yell, etc).  Then very tediously I just make 20 calls like void bang(), void yell() etc. Then, everything works perfectly .. you just call from anywhere sfx.bang() or sfx.poof() etc.  It's perfectly "solid" but a bit tedious!

Comment: @Fattie but couldn't you just play them all via one source via `PlayOneShot` then?

Comment: TBH I'm not really certain !!!!!!!  Is there a performance hit in "loading them each time"?  IDK, have never checked.  What about playing multiple at the same time?  Again IDK really.  For me the model Unity have used, is crap.  Let me try to explain myself this way, assume for a second that, every audio file (xyz.wav) HAD TO HAVE something like  an AudioSource.  So, in unity a png is useless, it has to be a texture or the like.  Again, in this theoretical scenario I propose, "everything would make sense" - the only meaningful audio "thing" would be a AudioSource and you'd have one for each...

Comment: ... I guess, essentially that's how I feel "it should be" and I basically follow that structure.  Every single time the audio guys make a new Explosion or whatever, for me it "just means" it needs it's own AudioSource.   I feel the Audio situation in Unity is a bit flakey!  So, that's my take anyways.  Also you see the "every sfx gets its own call" I describe.  I find, in practice, that's the way to go since, very often, different sound effects have different rules or behaviors. (Example "must be unique" or "play at most every 3 seconds" or "one fades another" or "never fade" .. etc etc)

Comment: (and I just program those rules in each one - it seems to me the sort of programming where: "The ad-hoc solution is really the only solution" :/ )  My take !   H.NewYear!

Comment: @Fattie Happy New Year, too ^^ IMO it makes totally sense though that every sound has a source, especially when using space blend and doppler. But yeah I see what you mean for e.g. having multiple looping sounds it would get tricky. ^^

Comment: also TBC .. I was purely thinking of the case of "sound effects" (that "play in the movie!")  Of course, some sounds are physically attached to something (feet, car, whatever) and move around in the scene. Here I was just thinking about "soundtrack!" sound effects that are in "the whole sound track!"

Answer (score 3):

At this line:
`s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>;`
you forgot to add the parantheses "**()**" after the `<AudioSource>`.
Add them before putting the semicolon "**;**".

The result should look like: `s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();`

Comment: Still questionable why OP would want to add multiple `AudioSource` components all to the same `gameObject` ;)

Comment: {one point is that you may wanna play more than one at the same time}